# micro_ros_agent build stuck on versal kr260

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon, ssh

I use a remote SSH connection to send commands to a Xilinx Kria KR260 running Ubuntu 22.04. I have followed the tutorial at this link: https://micro.ros.org/docs/tutorials/core/first_application_rtos/freertos/.
When building the micro_ros_agent using `ros2 run micro_ros_setup build_agent.sh` it blocks without specifying any errors. The output is something like:

```
Finished <<< drive_base_msgs [1min 16s]
Starting >>> micro_ros_msgs
Finished <<< micro_ros_msgs [10.5s]
Starting >>> micro_ros_setup
Finished <<< micro_ros_setup [0.68s]
Starting >>> micro_ros_agent
[6min 7.1s] [3/4 complete] [micro_ros_agent:build 7% - 4min 37.9s]
```

The output of the ssh connection at a certain point freezes.

Comment: The ros2 version is the latest (rolling).